# Method return values not consistent

Tags: php, class-design

This is a philosophical question, actually.
It's been a year I'm programming using PHP as a language and, as all of you know, PHP is very liberal as for the datatypes.
I was wondering: given that, is it a good practice to allow methods to return different kind of values?
Example: I'm used to set the variable that should be returned at a default value (usually false) and, if during the execution of the method everything goes well, the variable gets the value the successful execution has given.
Disclaimer: I try to document everything using PHPDoc.

Comment: Many of the built-in PHP functions does the same. Returning `false` or another resource.

Comment: I feel that this is a useful feature of PHP. If you document it well, it makes sense to do this for functions that can possibly go wrong (standard database lookups for instance) in order to fail gracefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a correct approach: returning boolean false allows the method/function to return other logical "false" values such as 0 or the empty string as valid while still allowing the caller to check its result with the `===` operator.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common approach, at least in PHP, and it isn't a bad practice.

It can be documented without problem using the PHPDoc convention: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.return.pkg.html

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering: given that, is it a
>   good practice to allow methods to
>   return different kind of values?

No, it's not. Not in PHP not in other languages. Better add an other method for a specific type of results.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is true? I often send back either a string or false, which are different data types. Are you saying I should now send back an empty string or the successful string for instance? It seems much easier to be able to use if (!$string) instead of if (!empty($string)) or if ($num < 1) or... etc depending on the data type.

Comment: powtac, it sounds like you want to put static typing on a dynamic language. If you feel the need for such a rule, wouldn't it be better to use a language that enforces it through technical means?

Comment: @linusU2982 How does your code look like when you call a function which returns different types?

Comment: The return types should have a common interface, like in OP's example -- they can both be compared to FALSE.

Comment: Yes maybe, but you ad something like if () arround them instead of moving this little logic into the method... But of course you can return different types, ... I don't recommend it.

Comment: @powtac: A standard block might be something like: if (condition): return false; else return $string. A very simplified example and many are much more involved (such as database functions that send back the result of a query, either false or the resource, different data types) - but you get the idea.